# How to get a list of views and their sizes?

Tags: sql-server

This query gives me a list of tables with their sizes. How do I change it so it gives me a list of the VIEWS instead?

```sql
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.Name
```

Comment: Have you considered replacing `sys.tables` with `sys.views`? Note that Views don't store data, they are pseudo tables. The only size they would have would be in relation to any indexes they have, if the view is schema bound.

Answer (score 1):

Views can have indexes. But maybe not.

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName
FROM 
    sys.views t
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

You can use this for Views with Indexes. But I recommend Left Outer Join:

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    s.Name AS SchemaName,
    p.rows,
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
    CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.views t
LEFT OUTER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    --AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    --AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.Name
```

Comment: It's bringing me only the views names as TableName and the SchemaName. The other columns are all null. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @Juliana, it seems your views are not indexed so there is no physical size to report. Normal views are just an encapsulation of a query.